# Sitecore 10.2 Forms Send Email action not sending email

Tags: sitecore-forms

Using Sitecore `10.2` with no EXM license. I have configured `MailServer` settings in `sitecore.config` and verified that it works by testing with the reset/forgot password link. For SMTP I am using Papercut SMTP on the local machine.

I have a couple of test forms where I selected the OOB `Send Email` action and there are only 2 fields: `Email field` and a single line text field for a name. When I submit any form, nothing happens. I added a Redirect to Url action after the Send Email action to see if the actions were executing and that action did function as expected.

There are no errors in the log file so I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: were you able to figure out the problem here and solve it? i'm facing the same issue

Comment: I don't believe I did. I'm no longer working on this project. @AME